# Slow download speed with Windows-based http server?

Tags: windows-7, http, connection

I've set a Windows 7-running computer with HFS (http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) in order for me to access some of my files through the internet. The machine in question is connected via 100 Mbits/s line with excellent visibility and very slow latency. Normally one can download with speeds reaching 10 MB/s on the machine and uploads are the same.

However, when I connect from my laptop at a place where the average http download speed is 2 MB/s to my home server, I can barely touch 150 KB/s.

Could someone explain to me whether there is an underlying (probably Windows-related) reason for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, yeah, are you sure you have a 100mbit sync line? Most enduser setups have much larger download than upload speed.

Comment: also, I guess you mean "low" latency, and not "slow" latency. You might want to provide a `tracert` from the laptop to the server.

Comment: Thank you for for the replies! Yes, indeed I meant "low latency". :)

And here are the results of the `tracert`: http://pastebin.com/6THDzKxP

Answer (score 0):

This is not expected.  your computer may be connected to your router via 100mbps, but you state you only get 2mbps http download.  Factoring in that upload is normally a lot slower than download (hence **A**dsl - Asymmetric digital subscriber line), this is not unexpected.  Your laptop can only download the files from outside your home network as fast as your computer can upload them.

It may be worth investing in a VPS, shared hosting or getting a SDSL or fibre connection installed in your hom eif you intend to use file sharing services.

Comment: Thanks, Fazer87, but I'm not on ADSL. I'm not on DSL either, it's a dedicated fibre-optic line with equal up and down speed.